# What is a union in SQL with two variables?

Tags: sql

Can someone explain to me what this question is asking of me exactly without giving me exactly the answer? I want to learn.

```
Let A={kirk,spock,mccoy} and B={spock,scotty,sulu}. What is A Union B?
Let A={Kirk,Spock,Mccoy} and B={Spock,Scotty,Sulu} what is A intersect B
Let A={Kirk,Spock,mccoy} and B={Spock,Scotty,Sulu}. What is A except B
```

Comment: Forget about SQL. Think about sets. `{kirk, spock, mccoy}` is a set with three members.

Comment: You really should be asked:  "What is A union all B?" because that is the construct most used in SQL.

Comment: It's perfectly clear what he is asking.  It is a basic question about set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is A UNION B?

```
The result considering A and B have the same number of columns,  
both of the result will be merged into on a single result set.
```

What is A INTERSECT B?

```
The result will be what both A and B have, can be similar to  
INNER JOIN and other similar solution/work around.
```

What is A Except B?

```
The result will be all the values of A that B does not have, can  
be similar to LEFT JOIN combined with filtering.
```

Good example: [*Example .pdf link*](http://faculty.utpa.edu/lianx/old_courses/CSCI4333_2014fall/MySQL-set-operators.pdf)
Credits to the owner of the .pdf

Comment: Ok, im still confuse. I understand the frist questoin but for the second will the answer only be {spock}? and for the last one im just straight confuse.

Comment: 2nd, yes only {spock}. 3rd, possible {Kirk, mccoy}. Also, don't forget to choose as answer. Like the last time I've answered your question rofl. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

Union means you are looking at the set that results when you place all elements of both sets into a new set.

Note that sets only have one occurrence of any given element

If you had BridgeOfficers={Kirk, Spock} and Scientists={Spock,McCoy}, then

BridgeOfficers Union Scientists would be {Kirk, Spock, McCoy} and **not** {Kirk, Spock, Spock, McCoy}

Comment: Oh, so for example the answer for this " Let A={kirk,spock,mccoy} and B={spock,scotty,sulu}. What is A Union B?" will be " A Union B = {Kirk,Spock,Scotty,Sulu}"